# In Firefox, how can I switch between always asking to save files, and automatically saving files to a download directory?

Tags: firefox, browser, download

I find myself switching between two setups a lot. During normal use I like to have Firefox ask me where to save all files and then I manually save them.

However when I need to download things in bulk (100+ items), this gets really tedious, so I open the settings and change the download preferences to something like this:

[image]

That way, when I click on a zip file, it just saves it. I don’t have to worry about the popup asking me where I want to save the file.

The catch is - I only want to do this when I need to download files in bulk. Normally I have this kind of setup:

[image]

Switching between these two “download profiles” gets really tedious and I am left wondering if there is some kind of solution that could auto-switch between both of these settings.

Does anyone know of a quick way to accomplish this besides just going into the settings and doing it manually? The only thing I could think of is to set up another profile with my desired settings and then switching between them when I need this functionality. But I'm really hoping there's an add-on for this.

I would REALLY appreciate any help or feedback!

Thanks so much,
Jay

Comment: There's really no other way unless someone codes a telepathy feature so it knows what you want at all times.

Comment: You can have different profiles with different settings but the effort required to toggle between them is pretty much the same as opening the settings tab so why bother?